# how to make a UIAlertView to hide automatically without User Interaction?

Tags: objective-c, ipad, ios4, xcode4

When the focus in a particluar rect of the screen  , it need to show up a message and need to hide automatically . Whether alertview will be flexible or any other way is there to implement the stuffs in iPhone and iPad .

Comment: No one here will do it for you. Show what you did, and you get help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use timer to close alert after some time, for example:

```
[[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:2 
                                 target:self 
                                 selector:@selector(closeAlert:) 
                                 userInfo:nil 
                                 repeats:NO] retain];
```

For more information look here: [NSTimer Class Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSTimer_Class/Reference/NSTimer.html)

Answer (score 0):

You can dismiss the alert after displaying for some seconds. 
Something like this : (Dismiss after 5 seconds)

```
 UIAlertView *yourAlert = [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"title" message:@"message" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:nil otherButtonTitles:nil]; 
        [yourAlert show];
        [self performSelector:@selector(dismiss:) yourAlert afterDelay:5.0];



-(void)dismiss:(UIAlertView*)alert
{
    [alert dismissWithClickedButtonIndex:0 animated:YES];
}
```